# Swift how to convert hash value number of text back into text

Tags: text, hash, swift

I am using swift to get some text a user puts into the textfield, and then I want to get the hash-value number of the characters they put in. I have this code to get the text and each of its  elements

```
  var plaintext = textField.text
        var countedtext = countElements(plaintext)
        for var index = 0; index < countedtext; ++index {
           let idx = advance(plaintext.startIndex, index)
            var element = plaintext[idx]
            var n = 1
            var newnumber = element.hashValue + n;

            newtext.append(newcharter)
```

I use `var newnumber = element.hashValue + n;` To get  the hash value of the character and plus it by one to get the letter after that letter. So if I was to type in "A" it would get the hash value number plus it by one and convert that number back into text form which would be "B". I check to see would this work by getting both hash values of A and B, "A" was `4799450059485595655` and "B" was `4799450059485595656`. I searched google but was not able to find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Zaph I am trying to create a caesar cipher by converting the letters eg a would be b, b would be c, c would be d so on

Comment: Essentially no. Consider getting the value of a 100 character string, the result is smaller, obviously there is no way to recover the original that contains more information. While single characters are small it is the same mechanism at work. Much of cryptography relies that a cryptographic hash is one-way.

Comment: @Zaph Would there be any way in which I could accomplish this

Comment: No, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Zaph I am trying to accomplish that if the user was to type in the string lets just say "abc" it would encode that to be "bcd"

Comment: OK, but hash functions are not going to be of any use for that. Just iterate over the string and create a new string with the updated characters. Either use a dictionary of character mappings or in the simple case get the underlying value, increment it, convert that to a character and use it. But we are in a unicode world now where characters are 21-bits and there are several different encodings. Probable the dictionary mapping the the best but watch out for non-ASCII characters like  & .

Comment: @Zaph So could I get the ASCII Value of a character in a string and then add one to that and convert it back into a stirng

Comment: Yes you can use ASCII. Becareful with "Z" and "z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash functions are unidirectional, that is they are not be reversible—by design.

What are you trying to accomplish?